f refers to the function with domain $[0, 2]$ and range $[0, 1]$. Sketch the graphs of $y=2f(x)$ and $y=f(2x)$.
The problem:
f refers to the function with domain $[0, 2]$ and range $[0, 1]$ whose graph is shown in the figure. Sketch the graphs of the indicated functions, and specify their domains and ranges.

$19$. $2f(x)$
$21$. $f(2x)$
How I solved problem 19:
Multiplying f(x) by 2 vertically stretches the graph by a factor of 2.

How I am thinking of solving problem 21:
Multiplying what is inside the function f(x) horizontally shortens the graph by a factor of 2.

My question:
Is one sentence provided to explain drawing the graphs the way I do a sufficient enough of an explanation? Need I provide further explanation? If so, what? These aren't problems I'm being graded solving by the way. I am merely practicing and wanting to understand.

I think your explanation is sufficient.  I might use the verbs dilation and compression, but stretch is fine, too.
